# Remove lines from a double-lined path to become a single-lined path

Tags: inkscape, path

I' quite new to Inkscape and came across something that I don't quite understand.

I made two simple paths. I tried filling them both, but as it appears, one of the two paths has double lines. This causes the fill to have an effect more similar to a stroke.

[image: single line]

This is my "normal" path.

[image: double line]

And this is the path in question. I have no idea how it became this way.
Is there any way to revert it to a single line?

[This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25176615/projects/greeter%20lines.svg) is a link to the file, in case that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is most probably that you used *Stroke to Path* on the double path.

As you paths were rather thin, you can recover a good approximation of the original path quite easily:

1. Select the “double path”.
2. Use *Path → Break Apart.* You should now have two almost identical shapes.
3. Delete one of the shapes.
4. Make the remaining shape an outline shape instead of a filled shape, for example as follows:

   1. Select a “normal” path.
   2. *Copy.*
   3. Select the shape.
   4. *Paste Style.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did the trick. I'm guessing that something like this shouldn't have been too hard to do. Forgive me, I'm new. ;)